# I've deleted user on Wordpress admin menu, but the userdata remains in phpmyadmin

Tags: wordpress

## Ideal

I'd like to recover userdata on Wordpress.

## What I've tried

I get backup data, and tried to install from phpmyadmin.
However, the deleted userdata remains in phpmyadmin.

So, I wondered if it would conflict when I install backup data.
And I don't get why there is still data in phpmyadmin.

## Summary

Any help and advice is appreciated.

Comment: I dont know if Im right or not, but if you have your backup, did you try to replace it manually using FTP?
what backups do you have? Just files or database too...?

Comment: I have both files and databases. I thought I couldn't edit user data on FTP but DB, but is it right?